# Displaying a ChartJS chart in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently trying to implement a graph into my django application. I have created a HTML page to display hard-coded details from my **views.py** class. When I load the webpage however I can't see the chart at all. Below is how i tried to implement the graph:

**Views**

In this class I am creating the views that will display on the graph. I have hard coded in some data for the time being just to get the graph up and running.

```
User = get_user_model()
#where i am viewing the chart, calling the html page.
class ChartView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'nutrition/chart.html', {"users": 10})



class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
#hard-coded data that i am trying to display on the chart
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        qs_count = User.objects.all().count()
        labels = ["Users", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        default_items = [qs_count, 12, 22, 13, 11, 15]
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

**urls**

The urls are i am using to display the pages are an extension onto `nutrition/`, urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
#url for the webpage to display the chart
    url('^chart/$', ChartView.as_view(), name='chart'),
#url to show the data using the django rest_framework
    url('^api/chart/data/$', ChartData.as_view()),
```

**HTML**

Here I am trying to display the chart. I am calling the variables from the view class and am plotting them on a bar chart.

```
<script>
    {% block jquery %}
        var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
        var defaultData = []
        var labels = [];
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            success: function(data) {
                labels = data.labels
                defaultData = data.default
                setChart()
            },
            error: function (error_data) {
                console.log("error")
                console.log(error_data)

            }
        })

        function setChart() {
              var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: defaultData,
                    }]
                },

            });
        }


    {% endblock %}
</script>

{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint="'{% url "nutrition:api-data" %}">
            <h1>Nutrition Chart</h1>
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

I have been following a tutorial that I have linked here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4Vmm3yZPgc

**Edit**

This is the screenshot with a solid border added showing where the graph should be displaying. 
[image]

Comment: Do you receive json data from the server?

Comment: If your urls are extension of `/nutrition`, then your `endpoint`, probably, should be equal to `/nutrition/api/chart/data/`

Comment: Apologies, of course the endpoint should equal to that, With that added however the chart still isn't visible on the webpage. I've added a solid border and can see where the chart should be displaying. I've attached a screenshot showing this.

Comment: Is that your full html? Where are your imports of `chartjs` javascript?

Comment: It's not my full HTML, i removed info such as background color etc... thought it wasn't necessary. My imported scripts are in the base.html file that is extended in this html file.

Answer (score 0):

did you try var endpoint = 'api/chart/data/' rather than var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/' in your html?